# break when value of a variable changes

Tags: debugging, go, delve

(1) Is there a way to stop the execution of a program when a variable changes its value?

Of course, I know we can set a breakpoint at some lines, but I would want just to set a variable, and when it changes, stop the program for debugging.

(2) I also want to see execution flow of a program (by logging to a file / printing on screen). Is there any way I can run my program and see the same (without stepping through each line)?

Please consider below example (https://play.golang.org/p/vOvW4GAM0j)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    r := rand.Intn(100)
    var i int

    if r%2 == 0 {
        i = 2
    } else {
        i = 1
    }

    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Now I want to break when value of i changes to non-zero value.  It may be from line 16 or line 18.

(1) Is there any way I can set (conditional) breakpoint so that it breaks when value of i changes OR I have to put breakpoint on both lines (16 and 18)?

(2) Also, I want to know how program was executed... like line13 then line15 then line17, line18... (assuming odd random number)

Thanks!

Comment: Please add info, that relates to debugging in delve ... because it confuses, when someone expects issue related to golang

Comment: assign a value to the variable and make a loop that will stop when the variable is different than that value. About the execution flow, a very common practise is just printing the variables and their values at certain important places of your code.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue.  I have updated my original post.

Answer (score -1):

You should try the [Goland IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/).

It has a fully functional [GO Debugger](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/features/) you can set watches.

[image: Debugger]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am bit familiar with Atom / VS Code IDEs.  There too we have fully functional Go Debugger with option to 'watch' variables.  I dont mind switching to Goland IDE if it can break when value of a variable changes.  Can I achieve the same with Goland IDE as I am unable to set break on variable values with Atom / VS Code.

Comment: OP is asking for a breakpoint, not a watch. The watch doesn't stop when the value changes.